# Why this program can not read text file in struct?

Tags: c, read

Here is my `a.txt` file which is of three lines. It does not contain any extra spaces or any non printable characters:

```
David Joans
018976
David12
```

Here is my code in `C` to read this file where I have created a structure to read it.Code::

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
        
#pragma pack(1)
        
typedef struct info {
  char name[15];
  int num;
  char pass[15];
}info;
        
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  FILE* fp = NULL;
  if (fp = fopen("a.txt", "r")) {
    info var;
    fread(&var, 1, sizeof(var), fp);
    printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n", var.name, var.num, var.pass);
  }
  else {
    perror("File can not be opened!!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
David Joans
018976
David12
171325241
David12
```

What is the actual problem here in the program? Help me figure out.

Answer (score 2):

The binary representation of the file does not need to match the actual binary representation of the struct `info`. The compiler is free to use padding space between the fields of the struct. So the only reliable way of doing what you want is to individually read each field from the file and assign it to the corresponding field in the struct. Something like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct info {
  char name[15];
  int num;
  char pass[15];
}info;

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  FILE* fp = NULL;
  if (fp = fopen("a.txt", "r")) {
    info var;
    char num_str[15];
    char *endl_ptr;

    fgets (var.name, sizeof (var.name), fp);
    fgets (num_str, sizeof (num_str), fp);
    fgets (var.pass, sizeof (var.pass), fp);

    /* parse num_str into an integer */
    var.num = strtol(num_str, NULL, 10);

    /* replace the trailing endline character by a NULL */
    if ((endl_ptr = strchr (var.name, '\n')))
        *endl_ptr = '\0';
    if ((endl_ptr = strchr (var.pass, '\n')))
        *endl_ptr = '\0';

    printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n", var.name, var.num, var.pass);
  }
  else {
    perror("File can not be opened!!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a file whose actual binary representation matches the one in the struct. For example, if the file is generated from a program that already has one `info` struct filled, a simple `write` of the struct to file will do the trick. However, this is not portable to other systems.

Comment: "individually read each field from the file and assign it to the corresponding field in the struct." Can you please elaborate with an example.

Comment: getting `int` value starting with **non-zero** digit is easy(by default may be starting `0` is not stored.) What if the `int num=09897`, it would get stored only `9897` and as `0` not being stored could be big issue...in some programs. Saying Big issuse I mean the actual problem may not be solved. Can  you please help me to solve this too??

Comment: If you need to preserve that leading 0, maybe it will be better to store it as a string, just like `name` and `pass`, instead of an integer. But then maybe you should validate that the given string is a well formed number.

Comment: See https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/ERR34-C.+Detect+errors+when+converting+a+string+to+a+number for the correct way of parsing numbers

Answer (score 0):

The `fread` reads 27 bytes from the file, because that is all there are, and sizeof (var) is bigger than that 2 x 15, + 4 for the int, and probably 2 padding). `fread` returns the count of bytes read, which you would normally check.

`fread` has no idea what its `void *ptr` represents: it does not know it is a `struct info`. It does not remove newlines, or terminate strings with a `\0` NUL character, or convert strings of digits to `int`. It simply smears the input bytes consecutively over the memory space occupied by the struct.

You have to parse the block of bytes yourself, using `string` functions, and `strtol` (there are man pages for both of those). So you need to read into an intermediate `char buf [80];` array.

The first 3 lines of your output are the whole of the input: fortunately, it did not crash the program because it hit a fortuitous NUL char.

The fourth line is probably the bytes "976D", re-accessed as an int from `info.num`, and with the byte order reversed because your CPU is little-endian.

The fifth line is re-accessing `info.pass`, which is where the last line of your input ended up.

`fread(&var, 1, sizeof(var), fp);` tries to get 36 bytes of data from the file, and stores them consecutively where the pointer `&var` tells it to. It does not know (or care) that &var points to any kind of struct, or how large the receiving area might be. `var` is *only* a memory address -- no size or type is attached. It also fails to read as many bytes as you asked for, because the text file is shorter than `sizeof(var)`.

By *re-accessed*, I mean that `printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n", var.name, var.num, var.pass);` outputs some data more than once. `printf` gets told the addresses of each part of the struct, but it still does not know the types or lengths of the struct members. The unterminated string `var.name` gets *all* the input data. Then the `var.num` starts at byte 16 of the input data again, takes 4 bytes of the text, and mistakenly assumes they are a meaningful int. Then the `var.pass` starts at byte 20 of the input again, and outputs another unterminated string.

Comment: Being a beginner(me) I have a lot of confusion in your answer. How `fread` recognizes its `void* ptr`?(as you mentioned there is no clue to `fread` to identify) Is there any legit way,it does so? And what do you mean by "re-accessing" `info.num` and `info.pass`?